# Starling cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, assets, starling-framework

Hey any help appreciated i've been mind boggled by the asset manager for a couple of days
Here is my Hawaii class that I'm trying to reference assets from my asset manager class (MapAssetLoadQeue). and I'm getting the Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Error, the error is thrown in my Hawaii class if I don't (Null) the Asset Manager reference, and it is thrown in my Loader Class haw.showHawaii()

Thanks!!!

```
package Maps
{
import flash.filesystem.File;

import Enqueue.MapAssetLoadQeue;

import starling.animation.IAnimatable;
import starling.animation.Juggler;
import starling.core.Starling;
import starling.display.Image;
import starling.display.MovieClip;
import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.Event;
import starling.textures.Texture;
import starling.textures.TextureAtlas;
import starling.utils.AssetManager;

public class Hawaii extends Sprite
{
    public var mal:MapAssetLoadQeue = new MapAssetLoadQeue;
    public var Ocean:Image;






    public function Hawaii():void{
        super();
        this.addEventListener   
                      (starling.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, showHawaii);
    }



    public function showHawaii(e:Event):void{



        if(mal.mapAssets != null) {

     Ocean = new Image(mal.mapAssets.getTexture("blue"));
     addChild(Ocean);
    Ocean.x = 0;
    Ocean.y = 0;
        }
    }
```

Here is my loader class where I load my assets, and here is where I get my error. haw.showHawaii(null) function. Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

```
package Assets {
import flash.filesystem.File;

import Enqueue.MapAssetLoadQeue;

import GUI.Wave;

import Maps.Hawaii;

import starling.animation.IAnimatable;
import starling.animation.Juggler;
import starling.core.Starling;
import starling.core.starling_internal;
import starling.display.Image;
import starling.display.MovieClip;
import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.Event;
import starling.textures.Texture;
import starling.textures.TextureAtlas;
import starling.utils.AssetManager;


public class Loader extends Sprite {

    var loadText: Texture = Texture.fromEmbeddedAsset(loadMCTexture);
    var loadXml: XML = XML(new loadMC0Xml());
    var loaderAtlas: TextureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(loadText, loadXml);
    public var loaderMovie: MovieClip = new MovieClip(loaderAtlas.getTextures("loading_"));
    public var mal: MapAssetLoadQeue = new MapAssetLoadQeue;
    public var wave:Wave = new Wave;
    public var haw:Hawaii;





    //Loader MovieClip size 720X233;
    [Embed(source = "/../Wavehunter/loadScreenAssets/wm/MovieClips/loader/loader_0.xml", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
    public static const loadMC0Xml: Class;

    [Embed(source = "/../Wavehunter/loadScreenAssets/wm/MovieClips/loader/loader_0.png")]
    public static const loadMCTexture: Class;


    // public var juggler:Juggler = Starling.juggler;
    /*
    ======================================================================
    Every Movieclip asset for the worldMap
    > Load WorldMap Assets on stage as Png and Make all alpha to 30%
    > and within each function make that png invible to false or remove
    > add MoviClip over the invisible png after load is processed
    =======================================================================
    */







    // Load WorldMap asset function
    public function mapLoader(): void {
        mal.requestWM();
        addChild(loaderMovie);
        loaderMovie.x = 347;
        loaderMovie.y = 277;
        loaderMovie.play();
        Starling.juggler.add(loaderMovie);
    }
    public function mapLdr(){
        loaderMovie.visible = true;
        addChild(loaderMovie);
        loaderMovie.x = 347;
        loaderMovie.y = 277;
        loaderMovie.play();
        Starling.juggler.add(loaderMovie);
    }
    //this function resizes the loader to original size and places at the bottom corner
    public function resizeLdr(){
        loaderMovie.width = 72;
        loaderMovie.height = 22;
        loaderMovie.x =1237;
        loaderMovie.y = 712;
    }

    public function callLoad(): void {



    public function callHawaii(): void {
        trace(" Hawaii is being runned");
        //mal.mapAssets.verbose = true;

        mal.mapAssets.loadQueue(function onGo(ratio: Number): void {

            trace("Hawaii percentage is", ratio);
            if (ratio == 1.0) {
                Starling.juggler.delayCall(function (): void {
                    loaderMovie.visible = false;
                    //addChild(haw.Ocean);
                //  addChild(haw);
                    trace("this is haw value",haw);
                    //trace("this is the function", haw.showHawaii(null));
                    haw.showHawaii(null);

                }, 0.30);

            }
        });
    }









    public function showMap() {
        // get texture by name
        addChild(mal);
        mal.accesMap();
        mal.hawaii.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED,removeMap);


    }
    // this code removes the HawaiiMap from the screen and goes directly to the wave
    public function removeMap(){
        trace("function initated"); 
        mapLdr();
        resizeLdr();
        mal.mapAssets.purge();
        mal.requestHawaii();
        callHawaii();

            mal.hawaii.removeEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED,removeMap);


    }

    public function Loader() {
        super();
    }
}
```

}

And here is my Asset Manager class

```
package Enqueue {
import flash.filesystem.File;
import Assets.MapAnimate;
import Assets.MapAssets;
import Maps.Hawaii;
import starling.animation.IAnimatable;
import starling.animation.Juggler;
import starling.animation.Transitions;
import starling.animation.Tween;
import starling.core.Starling;
import starling.core.starling_internal;
import starling.display.Button;
import starling.display.Image;
import starling.display.MovieClip;
import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.EnterFrameEvent;
import starling.events.Event;
import starling.textures.Texture;
import starling.textures.TextureAtlas;
import starling.utils.AssetManager;




public class MapAssetLoadQeue extends Sprite {
    public var mapAssets: AssetManager;

    public function MapAssetLoadQeue() {
        super();
    }


    public function requestHawaii():void {
        //  mapAssets.verbose =false;
    //  mapAssets = new AssetManager;
        var appDir:File = File.applicationDirectory;
        mapAssets.enqueue(appDir.resolvePath("IslandMaps/Hawaii"));
        //mapAssets.enqueue(Hawaii);
        mapAssets.verbose = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is all of your code, and if I'm not missing something obvious, I don't see you creating "haw" anywhere.  That is, you don't appear to have anything such as...

```
haw = new Hawaii();
```

...so, it would be null!

Comment: I add it on my game Class, which is my starling main class

Comment: It sounds like you're calling loader.loadQueue() before you do a loader.haw = new Hawaii()

Comment: You were right that was a problem,  I didn't initiate haw... but now I get the same error in my"Hawaii" class at Ocean = new Image(mal.mapAssets.getTexture("blue")); ... after tracing everything in that line, it states that mapAssets is null... can it mean that I'm calling mapAssets to early??? But I don't see how

Comment: I would use the debugger and actually step through the code.  Put some breakpoints where you're initializing your key objects (mal, haw, etc.), and make sure you get to them first.  You have a kind of complex flow, so stepping through will help you find if you're firing events before their landing zones are ready.